# Send message from popup to content script?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message

Suppose I want to run a content script when I click a button in the popup page in a google chrome extension?

I have tried the following:

```
//popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clicked);
  main();
});

function clicked(){
    chrome.tabs.getCurrent(
        function(tab){
            console.log(tab);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "doSomething");     
        }
    ); 
}
```

And in the content script:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse){
        console.log("hello world");
    }
);
```

The problem is that the `tab` in the callback from `chrome.tabs.getCurrent( )` is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you given permissions for tabs in manifest.json as shown here.

```
 "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
```

Moreover tab.id which the following code returns is of popup view **(NOT A CONTENT SCRIPT TAB.ID)**

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(
        function(tab){
            console.log(tab);
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "doSomething");     
        }
    );
```

If you want to send message to tab you are browsing use following code's tab.id, it gives correct results

```
chrome.tabs.query({"status":"complete","windowId":chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,"active":true}, function(tabs){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(tabs[0]));
     console.log(tabs[0].id); 
});
```

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: tabs.query returns an array.  Should probably mention that status is optional.  `"windowId":chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT` can be replaced with `"currentWindow:true` looks a little neater.  And maybe a link to tabs.getCurrent so they can reread the docs, lots of people get that one wrong....I sure did a bunch of times ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @Sudarshan is valid and works fine, but I just found another solution to my problem. Just thought i put it here:

```
function clicked() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"console.log('hello world');"});
}
```

It will inject and execute the script.