# Communicate between popup and content script in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a chrome extension but I can not send message from popup to content script. Please tell me where's the problem.

The popup script code :

```
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('#button').click(function(){
              chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},function(tabs) {
                     chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hello"});
        });
    });
});
```

The content script code :

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender) {
  alert("Contentscript has received a message from from background script: '" + request.message + "'");
  });
```

this is manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "name" : "First My Chrome Extension",
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "description" : "The first web-app using chrome extension technology",
  "icons" : {
    "16" : "images/icon16px.png",
    "48" : "images/icon48px.png",
    "128" : "images/icon128px.png"
  },


 "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/background.js"]

  },



  "browser_action" :{
    "default_icon":{
      "48" : "images/icon48px.png"
    },
    "default_title" : "Nghoangvutn",
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts":[
  {
    "matches":[
      "<all_urls>"
      ],
    "js" : [
      "scripts/jquery.js",
      "scripts/content.js"
      ]

  }
    ],

  "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "storage"
    ]

}
```

Comment: Any error info in popup and web page console?

Comment: there is no error info. It just doen't work. Maybe the message passing was fail. I don't know where's the problem

Comment: Check these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646389/send-message-from-popup-to-content-script and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108906/chrome-extension-message-passing-from-popup-to-content-script

Comment: Such problems are solved in a matter of seconds or minutes if you debug both the popup and content script by setting breakpoints.

Comment: yeah, thanks woxxom, it work.

Comment: I have the same problem....

Answer (score 2):

The content script code should be updated to use the following method [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage). Note the change from `chrome.extension` to `chrome.runtime`.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
 function(request, sender) {
   alert("Contentscript has received a message from from background script: '" + request.message + "'");
});
```

Comment: I followed your help, but nothing changes, content scripts doesn't work.

Comment: It should be added to pages either dynamically or statically using the manifest file.